# Dynamic stored procedure with large amount of columns

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Take an example that i got a large amount of columns say 50 and i want to write a stored procedure that inserts and updates data to the table...
i want to know if it is any other way to dynamically write the stored procedure
without hard coding column names?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the column names from sys.columns...

```
SELECT 
    ColumnName = c.name
FROM
    sys.columns c
WHERE
    c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('DatabaseName.Schema.TableName')
ORDER BY
    c.column_id;
```